# Error when I include a dash in the ylabel() option of twoway scatter

Tags: stata

```
version 15.1
clear

set obs 10
gen n = _n
gen x = n*10

* This works
twoway scatter n x, ylabel(1"1989" 2"1973-78")

* This doesn't work
twoway scatter n x, ylabel(1"1989-95" 2"1973-78")
```

The second plot results in the error `95"" invalid name`. Why is this occurring?

The error has something to do with the `-` character, but it is exactly the same character that is used for `2"1973-78"` in the first plot, which works (I have copy-pasted it).

I am running Stata 15.1 SE on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm your problem in Stata 16.1, which is the latest as I write.

This does work:

```
twoway scatter n x, ylabel(1 "1989-95" 2 "1973-78")
```

All the relevant examples at https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?axis_label_options include spaces between numbers and the text strings to display.

I don't recollect an explicit rule to that effect, and it's your experience so far that you can get away by omitting the spaces, but evidently that doesn't always work.

Calling this a parsing issue is just giving the problem a name. I don't have a low-level explanation of why one worked and the other didn't.